# How do I return correctly formatted name:value pairs from mongodb, using the C# mongo driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

When I'm getting BsonDocuments returned in my C# API from a mongoDB server they are coming back in the following format:

```
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "_id",
                    "value": "01007"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "BELCHERTOWN"
                },
                {
                    "name": "loc",
                    "value": [
                        -72.410953,
                        42.275103
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "pop",
                    "value": 10579
                },
                {
                    "name": "state",
                    "value": "MA"
                }
            ]
```

I would like the result returned to be more like this:

```
            "data": [
                {
                    "_id": "01007",
                    "city":"BELCHERTOWN",
                    "loc":
                        [-72.410953,
                         42.275103],
                    "pop":"10579",
                    "state":"MA"
                }
            ]
```

Could anyone give me an idea if this is something I need to change in Mongo, or is it likely to be something I'm doing in my API that's causing the problem. I've tried googling it but it seems a difficult problem to search for.

I'll happily share some code from my API too if anyone thinks that will help, but I'm fairly sure I've used quite a standard setup when it comes to connecting to and calling the database.

**EDIT: call from Mongo service in C#**

```
        internal async Task<ICollection<BsonDocument>> SearchAsync(SearchParameters parameters, string db, string collection)
        //internal async Task<SearchResult> SearchAsync(SearchParameters parameters, string db, string collection, string url )
        {
            //gets mongo connection string and database name from the
            //MongoDatabaseSettings class which gets it from appsettings.json
            var client = new MongoClient(_dbsettings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(db);

            //uses the name from MongoCollectionName variable, set by MongoDatabaseSettings.cs, again supplied from appsettings.json
            _bsondocs = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);

            var indexFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;

            //this part performs the actual search
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters.Q))
                indexFilter &= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Text(parameters.Q);

            //get data with paging
            var data = await _bsondocs.Find(indexFilter)
                .Skip((parameters.Page - 1) * parameters.PageLimit)
                .Limit(parameters.PageLimit)
                .ToListAsync();

            return data;

        }
```

Controller

```
        //uses the mongo service to return all results of a collection (collection is specified in application json)
        [HttpGet("{db}/{collection}", Name = "CollectionRoute")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] SearchParameters parameters,
            [FromRoute]string db, [FromRoute]string collection)
        {
            //create a bool which will be set to true if the db/collection passed in the url matches one in the approved list
            Boolean approved = false;

            foreach (var database in databases)
            {
                foreach (var col in database.Collections)
                {
                    if (database.Name == db && col == collection)
                    {
                        approved = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            //if db/collection is in approved list then deal with request, else return a bad request
            if (approved == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //SearchResult result = await _mongoService.SearchAsync(parameters, db, collection, url);
                    var documents = await _mongoService.SearchAsync(parameters, db, collection);
                    var totalRecords = await _mongoService.getTotalRecordsCount(parameters, db, collection);

                    var result = new SearchResult()
                    {
                        //Data = documents,
                        SearchParameters = parameters,
                        TotalRecords = totalRecords,
                        Links = new List<Link>(),
                        BsonResults = new List<BsonResult>()
                    };

                    //for each of the bsondocuments in the collection, make a new 'bsonresult' so a link to self can be added.
                    foreach (var doc in documents)
                    {
                        var Id = doc.GetValue("_id")
                            .ToString();

                        result.BsonResults.Add(new BsonResult
                        {
                            Data = doc,
                            Links = new List<Link>
                        {
                            new Link
                            {
                                Method = "Get",
                                Rel = "Self",
                                Href = Url.Action("GetRecord", "Mongo", new { id = Id }, Request.Scheme)
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    }

                    foreach (var r in result.BsonResults)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(r);
                        Console.WriteLine(r.Data);
                    }

                    //set the current page of the search result
                    if (documents != null && documents.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        result.CurrentPage = parameters.Page;
                    }

                    //use the pagelinkbuilder to create
                    var linkBuilder = new PageLinkBuilder(Url, "CollectionRoute", parameters, totalRecords);

                    if (linkBuilder.FirstPage != null)
                    {
                        result.Links.Add(new Link
                        {
                            Href = linkBuilder.FirstPage,
                            Rel = "First Page",
                            Method = "Get"

                        });
                    }
                    if (linkBuilder.PreviousPage != null)
                    {
                        result.Links.Add(new Link
                        {
                            Href = linkBuilder.PreviousPage,
                            Rel = "Previous Page",
                            Method = "Get"

                        });
                    }
                    if (linkBuilder.NextPage != null)
                    {
                        result.Links.Add(new Link
                        {
                            Href = linkBuilder.NextPage,
                            Rel = "Next Page",
                            Method = "Get"

                        });
                    }
                    if (linkBuilder.LastPage != null)
                    {
                        result.Links.Add(new Link
                        {
                            Href = linkBuilder.LastPage,
                            Rel = "Last Page",
                            Method = "Get"

                        });
                    }

                    if (linkBuilder.Self != null)
                    {
                        result.Links.Add(new Link
                        {
                            Href = linkBuilder.Self,
                            Rel = "Self",
                            Method = "Get"
                        });
                    }

                    return Ok(result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
                }
            }

            else return BadRequest("The name of the database or collection specified is invalid.");
        }
```

Comment: How are you converting query results into initially showed string representation?

Comment: It happens there in the mongoservice, the _bsondocs variable contains the list of all bsonDocuments from the mongo server. The search parameters are used to filter the data using the indexFilter variable. So the data variable is the collection of bson documents with the filter and some logic for paging applied. The data variable is returned to the controller - but there are no further changes made to it in there.

Comment: Uhm... `_bsondocs_  is an `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>`; its `Find` method returns (logically) a *cursor*  over the result set; `ToListAsync` returns a `Task<List<BsonDocument>>` and your code `await`s it, so `data` is a `List<BsonDocument>`; your method is returning the list... how do you obtain the `"data": [{"name": "_id","value": "01007"}, ...]` string?

Comment: Hello, apologies, I'm fairly new to mongo and c#, I've edited my reponse to include the code from my controller. The documents variable in here is the result of my SearchAsync method (data). From here I add each of the documents in that collection to a new searchresult so I can store links and other useful information with the BsonDocument. The stuff after that is just generating links.

Comment: Have you tried invoking `ToJson` on `BsonDocument`'s  instances?